# How to display only one li element sliding one after another in Bootstrap Carousel slider?

Tags: responsive

I have created bootstrap Carousel slider with 3 li elements. I want to display only one li element sliding one after another.

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  text-column navkey1">

  <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#javo-wall-of-fame-slider" class="left ">
    <label class="keyword-nav"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</label> </a>

  <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" role="button" href="#javo-wall-of-fame-slider" class="right ">
    <label class="keyword-nav"><span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Next</span> </label>
  </a>

</div>

<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  text-column featured-image resto">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">

        <div class="item active">
          <ul class="row">
            <li class="simple" id="">
              <div class="content-box">
                <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12 restaurant1">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant-main">
                    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 restaurant-info pull-left">
                      <h3>Windsol Restaurant 11</h3>
                      <p> 520 1st floor, Manhattan, New York</p>
                      <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 215-556-8561</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-2   pull-left restaurant-rating">
                      <p><span class="rating"> 4.2</span>/10</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="simple" id="">
              <div class="content-box">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-left restaurant-div restaurant-div-small">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant2">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant-main2">
                      <div class="col-lg-9  col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 restaurant-info pull-left">
                        <h3>Windsol Restaurant 12</h3>
                        <p> 520 1st floor, Manhattan, New York</p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 215-556-8561</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-8  pull-left restaurant-rating">
                        <p><span class="rating"> 2.9</span>/10</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>


            <li class="simple" id="">
              <div class="content-box">
                <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-left restaurant-div restaurant-div-small">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  restaurant3">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant-main3">
                      <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 restaurant-info pull-left">
                        <h3>Windsol Restaurant 13</h3>
                        <p> 520 1st floor, Manhattan, New York</p>
                        <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 215-556-8561</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10   pull-left restaurant-rating">
                        <p><span class="rating"> 3.0</span>/10</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
        </div>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <ul class="row">
          <li class="simple" id="">
            <div class="content-box">
              <div class="col-lg-4 pull-left col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12 restaurant1">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant-main">
                  <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 restaurant-info pull-left">
                    <h3>Windsol Restaurant 21</h3>
                    <p> 520 1st floor, Manhattan, New York</p>
                    <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 215-556-8561</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-2   pull-left restaurant-rating">
                    <p><span class="rating"> 4.2</span>/10</p>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="simple" id="">
            <div class="content-box">
              <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-left restaurant-div restaurant-div-small">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant2">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant-main2">
                    <div class="col-lg-9  col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 restaurant-info pull-left">
                      <h3>Windsol Restaurant li 22</h3>
                      <p> 520 1st floor, Manhattan, New York</p>
                      <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 215-556-8561</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-8  pull-left restaurant-rating">
                      <p><span class="rating"> 2.9</span>/10</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="simple" id="">
            <div class="content-box">

              <li class="simple" id="">
                <div class="content-box">
                  <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-12 pull-left restaurant-div restaurant-div-small">
                    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  restaurant3">
                      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 restaurant-main3">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 restaurant-info pull-left">
                          <h3>Windsol Restaurant 23</h3>
                          <p> 520 1st floor, Manhattan, New York</p>
                          <p><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i> 215-556-8561</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-10   pull-left restaurant-rating">
                          <p><span class="rating"> 3.0</span>/10</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12  heading ">
      <h1>Everyday Interesting</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 text-column">
      <ul id="filters" class="clearfix">
        <li class="list-inlines keyword"><span class="filter active" data-filter="aloknath rajni bollywood santa banta sita">ALL</span></li>
        <li class="list-inlines keyword"><span class="filter" data-filter="sita bollywood">ETIQUETTE</span></li>
        <li class="list-inlines keyword"><span class="filter" data-filter="rajni aliknath banta">HUMOR</span></li>
        <li class="list-inlines keyword"><span class="filter" data-filter="sita">LANGUAGE & GRAMMAR</span></li>
        <li class="list-inlines keyword"><span class="filter" data-filter="bollywood rajni">POLITICS</span></li>
        <li class="list-inlines keyword"><span class="filter" data-filter="rajni banta sita santa bollywood">TECHNOLOGY</span></li>
        <li class="list-inlines keyword"><span class="filter" data-filter="aloknath sita bollywood">YOUTUBE</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12  col-xs-12 text-column navkey">
      <label class="keyword-nav"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
      <label class="keyword-nav"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-column category-images featured-image">
      <div id="portfoliolists">
        <div class="col-lg-12 ul-wrapper">

          <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6  portfolio aloknath mix_all" data-cat="aloknath" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left  image-div left-pad">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 joke1">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 img-title">
                    <span class="img-title-main">ALOK NATH JOKES</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6  portfolio bollywood mix_all" data-cat="bollywood" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left   image-div">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 joke2">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 img-title">
                    <span class="img-title-main">BOLLYWOOD TWEETS</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6  portfolio rajni mix_all" data-cat="rajni" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left  image-div">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 joke3">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 img-title">
                    <span class="img-title-main">RAJNIKANTH JOKES</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6  portfolio banta mix_all" data-cat="banta" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left  image-div">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 joke3">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 img-title">
                    <span class="img-title-main">SANTA N BANTA</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6  portfolio santa mix_all" data-cat="santa" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left  image-div">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 joke3">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 img-title">
                    <span class="img-title-main">SANTABANTA JOKES</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class=" col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6  portfolio sita mix_all" data-cat="sita" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
            <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
              <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 pull-left  image-div">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 joke3">
                  <div class="col-lg- col-md-12  col-sm-12 col-xs-12 img-title">
                    <span class="img-title-main">SITA N GITA   </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center heading ">
      <h1 style="font-weight: 500;">INFORMATION </h1>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered col-md-1  col-sm-1 col-xs-3 underline"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-column last-div" id="counters">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-left text-right">
        <img src="images/listings.png" alt="listings" class="listings"> <br>
        <p class="count-top-listings ">200<br></p>
        <p class="count-bottom-listings">LISTINGS<br></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4  col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-left text-center ">
        <img src="images/star-ratings.png" alt="listings" class="listings">
        <p class="count-top">400<br></p>
        <p class="count-bottom">REVIEWS<br></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 pull-left text-left">
        <img src="images/couple.png" alt="listings" class="listings">
        <p class="count-top">400<br></p>
        <p class="count-bottom"> USERS<br></p>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying the Carousel is not rotating through your `li` elements? It loads up the first on the page and just sits there?

If this is the case do you have the interval set in your `document.ready()`

```
<script>
  $function(){
     $('#myCarousel').carousel({
     interval: 5000 //5 seconds
     });
  });
</script>
```